# Renderizar html con atributos de AngularJS (Angular 1) desde el controlador

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, aplicación-web, controller

Actualmente estoy intentando renderizar un html desde un método en el controlador de angular así:

```
    me.func1 = function (codDep) {

    var str = '';

    angular.element(document.querySelector('#ligas')).remove();

    str += '<div id="ligas">';

    for (i = 0; i < me.Model.Ligas.length; i++) {
        var lig = me.Model.Ligas[i];
        str += '<a href="#" id="' + lig.Id + '" class="list-group-item" data-ng-click="me.func2()">' + lig.Nombre + '</a>';
    }

    str += '</div>';

    angular.element(document).find('#' + idElement).after(str);
};
```

El html es perfectamente renderizado hasta con los ***data-ng*** de angulajs de ésta manera:
`<a href="#" id="217" class="list-group-item" data-ng-click="me.func2()">Esto es un link</a>` .

El problema que tengo es que cuando hago click sobre el elemento creado anteriormente no ejecuta el ***data-ng-click="me.func2()"*** que contiene el siguiente método:

```
    me.func2 = function () {
    alert('Funcion #2 ejecutada');
};
```

Soy nuevo con el framework, realmente no sé si esto es posible (no debería ser cosa del otro mundo), o estoy haciendo algo mal.

De antemano agradecido por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1):

Angel como estas?

Creo que tu problema se debe a que hay que recompilar el código que inyectas al HTML. El tema es que AngularJS no se da cuenta de que agregas atributos de AngularJS programaticamente a menos que se lo indiques. Para lograr esto tenes que usar el servicio $compile de AngularJS.
Inyecta el servicio y el $scope en tu código y prueba lo siguiente:

```
 me.func1 = function (codDep) {

    var str = '';

    angular.element(document.querySelector('#ligas')).remove();

    str += '<div id="ligas">';

    for (i = 0; i < me.Model.Ligas.length; i++) {
        var lig = me.Model.Ligas[i];
        str += '<a href="#" id="' + lig.Id + '" class="list-group-item" data-ng-click="me.func2()">' + lig.Nombre + '</a>';
    }

    str += '</div>';

    angular.element(document).find('#' + idElement).after($compile(str)($scope));
};
```

---

Referencia https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

---

Finalmente cuéntame como te fue! 
**Saludos!**

Answer (score 0):

Mira, intenta con esto en tu código.

```
me.func1 = function (codDep) {

var str = '';

angular.element(document.querySelector('#ligas')).remove();

str += '<div id="ligas">';

for (i = 0; i < me.Model.Ligas.length; i++) {
    var lig = me.Model.Ligas[i];
    str += '<a href="#" id="' + lig.Id + '" class="list-group-item" ng-click="me.func2()">' + lig.Nombre + '</a>';
}

str += '</div>';

angular.element(document).find('#' + idElement).after(str);
};
```

Comment: No hubo diferencia, en realidad el data es utilizado para mantener un código html válido.

Comment: Haz una prueba. Crea un botón y ejecuta la función **me.func2**. Si te ejecuta normalmente el error está en **me.func1**

Comment: Si, el funciona llamándolo desde la vista directamente. Y bueno en realidad no se si eso que estoy haciendo en func1 sea posible, en teoría debería funcionar.